# MS Word 2010-016: How to create or define a new "Number Style"

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering, list

Maybe this is a simple question, but I can't find any solutions for it. Is there a possible way (or even a tricky way) to define or create our own "Number Style" in Microsoft Word?

As you see in this image, our choices are very limited!

[image]

For example I need to add list numbers from α to ω automatically or for any item-list steps, show my own characters there (instead of these default Number Styles).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you can create a new number format via

Menu --> Home --> Paragraph --> Numbering Icon [down arrow] --> Define New Number Format

This displays this dialogue:

[image: Word Define Number Format]

In the "Number style" field, you have various options. On my machine I see there also e.g. a Bulgarian alphabet - which is obviously there because I have set Windows to provide also a Bulgarian keyboard (in addition to my ordinary German). I would therefore suppose that you can extend the list of Number styles available by edding keyboard layouts to Windows, or languages to your version of Office.

I do however so far not see a way to create a *custom* list of characters, words or whatever to be used to replace the numbers... If this is what you need, you could, as a workaround, create a VBA script that removes the "numbering" property from paragraphs in a given document and puts a character (or word or whatever) of your liking on top of the paragraph, and those characters or words could be taken out of an array (i.e. a list) you previously defined. Would not be too complicated to program this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answer for the general case, but there is a way for creating a list with greek characters.

- Open *Define new Multilevel list* dialog box
- In dropdown *Number style for this level* select a, b, c, ...
- Click on *Font* button
- Inside Font dialog box, select the *Symbol* font

Your list will now use lowercase Greek letters for numbering. The caveat is that it order doesn't follow classical Greek alphabet, but some sort of phonetic equivalent to Latin alphabet. It starts ok a -> α, b -> β, but after that c -> χ (chi is stand in for c), d -> δ, and so on.

It isn't exactly what you asked, but it can provide a bit of flair to your lists. I suspect you could do exactly Greek alphabet with some other font.

Comment: The third letter in greek is gamma

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. This method doesn't produce list in exact order of Greek alphabet. Instead it creates list in order of Latin alphabet but with Greek characters. Chi is third, because its sounds like "c". Delta is fourth, epsilon is fifth, but then phi is sixth (phi sounds like f), gamma is seventh, and so on.