# Define new number style, not number format

Tags: microsoft-word

As you know, Word has some predefined number style, for example, "1,2,3,..." or "A,B,C,..". Is there a way to define a new number style?

Specifically, Arabic alphabetic number style in Word starts with "أ" and continues with "ب" and "ج" and ... . I want a number style that start with "الف" and continues  with "ب" and "ج" and ... .
Related question: [MS Word 2010-016: How to create or define a new "Number Style"](https://superuser.com/questions/1288444/ms-word-2010-016-how-to-create-or-define-a-new-number-style)